# Why doesn't `if` work in Python Turtle , it seems to me I wrote everything correctly

Tags: python

```
import turtle
turtle.color ("black", "red")
turtle. speed (10)
while True:
    a = input("введите действие (вперед-w, назад-s, влево-a, направо-d):"))
    if a == "w":
        u = int(input("насколько?:"))
        turtle.forward (u)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Ww9.png)

`if` does not work in Python turtle,
please help

Почему в Python turtle не работает  "IF"?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Check the brackets in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem is this line:

```
а = input("..."))
```

You have one too many closing parentheses.  Try not to confuse the parentheses inside the quotes and the ones outside.  Running your code should have produced an error:

```
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

Comment: I have already noticed and removed these errors, but the program still does not work

Comment: @user17838462 If I take your code, I delete the last bracket on line 5, run (the turtle and input text appear), enter ``w`` (the second text appears), and then enter ``10``, and the turtle moves by 10. The program does not have a condition of termination and it is necessary to stop it forcibly. The question is answered, you should accept it and when you have the next question, create a new one (preferably without syntax errors).

Comment: @user17838462 Do you use English `w`? There is a similar letter [051C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) on your native keyboard. Alternatively, you can contact https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @david-lukas, I use english - w

Comment: I realized, I wrote in variable  - а, Russian, this is probably some kind of bug, because the program used to accept Russian

Comment: @user17838462, it may not have been a bug but an inconsistency -- one reference to the the variable might have been an ASCII 'a' and the other a Russian 'a'.  I do recall tweaking this when I transferred your code from image to text.